# Edittext text not visible if window title is removed

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, android-edittext, window-managers

In my application if window title is removed  all edittext are not visible in activity which is of dialog theme.
I'm not getting why this is happening.

XML FILE-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"

    android:gravity="center" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/small_icon" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edittext"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:numeric="integer"
                android:password="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

In activity oncreate-

```
   requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
   setContentView(R.layout.reset_password);
```

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. Please brief your question with some more relevant code and screenshot.

Comment: rounded_edittext is having which bg color? provide edittext some color may the bg color and text color is same that why it may seen to you

Comment: text color is black and in rounded_edittext bg is white.

Answer (score 0):

try this code .....

```
                /* REMOVE TITLE OF APPLICATION */
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    /* SET ACTIVITY TO FULL SCREEN MODE */
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try insert ScrollView inside another LinearLayout.